# How to see Overflow: hidden items

Tags: css

Please explain how I would see the hidden part that is the cropped part of my text without using scroll in [css](/questions/tagged/css).

**Example**

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Because the hidden part is important. The table property is fixed.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I want the `<td>` text to expand and follow the `<td>` height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make simple js-script

```js
var a = document.querySelector(".yourClass");
a.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  a.classList.toggle("yourClass--show");
});
```

```css
/*class you wanna display*/
.yourClass {
overflow:hidden;
}

.yourClass--show {
overflow: visible;/*or smth you want*/
}
```